# since it has access to outside object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute a small snippet code and see. I got the following results. Gave explanation for each of the results. Can you guys tell me whether its correct or not?

```
var myObject = {
    foo: "bar",
    func: function() {
        var self = this;
        console.log("outer func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
        console.log("outer func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
        (function() {
            console.log("inner func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
            console.log("inner func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
        }());
    }
};
myObject.func();


outer func:  this.foo = bar ------------> since it has access to outside object
outer func:  self.foo = bar ------------> since it has access to outside object
inner func:  this.foo = undefined ------------> dont know why its undefined
inner func:  self.foo = bar ------------> since it has access to variable self
```

Comment: for inner function it will again creates its own `this`

Answer (score 2):

It is `undefined` in the inner function because it's inside a **self-invoking function**.  In a self-invoking function, the value of `this` becomes the `window` global object.  So since `window.foo` is undefined, `this.foo` is also undefined since `this === window` in that inner function.

Comment: for the inner function when i change into self1 it still shows undefined http://jsfiddle.net/5o1fszmk/

Comment: That's because IIFEs `this` is the global object (or undefined if in strict mode), `var self1 = this` is behaving as expected

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
    (function() {
        console.log(this);
        console.log("inner func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
        console.log("inner func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
    }());
```

is an immediately executed function that is binding `this` to the global object, meaning the `this.foo` is actually looking at global variables.

The purpose of assigning `var self = this;` in it's enclosing function is to allow you to access the outer function's `this` from the inner function.

If desired, you can change the context given to the immediately executing function using `Function.prototype.call()`,

```
    (function() {
        console.log("inner func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
        console.log("inner func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
    }).call(this); // outer this now === inner this
```